# How can you rearrange characters to make a word existing in the dictionary?

Tags: java, string, char, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I've been trying to tweak little bits of code here and there to make my output correct. I am trying to have my code be able to rearrange the letters in a word to make other words that exist in words.txt, from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordsInWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "/Users/laptop/Desktop/Test.txt";
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String c = r.readLine();
        while (c != null) {
            b.append(c);
            b.append(" ");
            c = r.readLine();
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in = s.nextLine();
        char[] input = new char[in.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = in.charAt(i);
        }
        char[] temp = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            if (i < b.length() - 1 && b.charAt(i) == ' ' && b.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {
                boolean found = false;
                int counter = 0;
                while (!found) {
                    counter++;
                    if (b.charAt(i + counter) == ' ') {
                        found = true;
                        temp = new char[counter - 1];
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + counter; j++) {
                            temp[j] = b.charAt(j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (Arrays.asList(input).contains(temp)) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my tweaked code:

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WordsInWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "/Users/laptop/Desktop/words.txt";
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String[] words;
        String c = r.readLine();
        int a=0;
        while (c != null) {
            c = r.readLine();
            a++;
        }
        words=new String[a];
        a=0;
        r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String temp=r.readLine();
        while (temp != null) {
            words[a]=r.readLine();
            temp=words[a];
            a++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
            List<String> found = findRearranged(input, words);
            System.out.println("For '" + input + "' found: " + Arrays.toString(found.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<String> findRearranged(String input, String[] words) {
        List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String w : words) {
            if (hasSameLetters(w, input)) {
                found.add(w);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public static boolean hasSameLetters(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() != b.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        while (a.length() > 0) {
            for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
                int index = a.indexOf(c);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    a = a.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is rearranging the characters necessary?
Rearranging the input and searching through dictionary to find equal word could take lot's of computing time, single few letter word can have many permutations.

For me, it looks like you want to find the words in dictionary for input word containing same letters (in other words, if the input word would be rearranged, it would give you the existing word in dictionary). Probably checking if both words are having exactly same letters, regardless their position in both strings should satisfy the requirement.

Here's the sample for that approach:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //the words in dictionary
        String[] words = {"words", "sword", "nord", "chord", "score", "cores", "mors", "xyz", "scores", "ordsw"};
        String[] input = {"sword", "score", "tores", "nores"};
        for (String i : input) {
            List<String> found = findRearranged(i, words);
            System.out.println("For '" + i + "' found: " + Arrays.toString(found.toArray()));
        }
    }

    public static List<String> findRearranged(String input, String[] words) {
        List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String w : words) {
            if (hasSameLetters(w, input)) {
                found.add(w);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public static boolean hasSameLetters(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() != b.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        while (a.length() > 0) {
            for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
                int index = a.indexOf(c);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    a = a.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this outputs in:

```
For 'sword' found: [words, sword, ordsw]
For 'score' found: [score, cores]
For 'tores' found: []
For 'nores' found: []
```

Edit:
I see the assumption is that every word is in its own line.
I saw that you already came up with counting the words in the file, but still in that case it's better to use Collections which are having dynamic size.
Here's fixed sample:

```
public class WordsInWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "C:\\Users\\masta\\IdeaProjects\\podstawka-spring-java\\words.txt";
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String c = r.readLine();
        while (c != null) {
            words.add(c);
            c = r.readLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Words: " + words.get(i));
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        List<String> found = findRearranged(input, words);
        System.out.println("For '" + input + "' found: " + Arrays.toString(found.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<String> findRearranged(String input, List<String> words) {
        List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String w : words) {
            if (hasSameLetters(w, input)) {
                found.add(w);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public static boolean hasSameLetters(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() != b.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        while (a.length() > 0) {
            for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
                int index = a.indexOf(c);
                if (index >= 0) {
                    a = a.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to tweak your code to make it use my dictionary and have only one input by a Scanner(System.in), but it is screaming nullPointer whenever hasSameLetters or findRearranged is called.

Comment: To use the arrays in your case first thing you would need to do is count the amount of words in dictionary before you initialize the words array. Arrays in java has fixed/constant size. So initializing the words with `new String[a]` will always has 0 elements. Give me a sec I'll change it to use the Lists.

Comment: Sorry for nagging so much, but for some odd reason after I give it input, the arrayList found is empty. Is there a reason for this I don't understand?       EDIT: I removed printing all words in words.txt

Comment: Also, I meant to have the program find words that could be made from the word's letters. (ex. SWIMMING contains SWIM, WIN, WING, SING, MIMING, etc.)

Comment: in that case, if the input string is smaller then there's no match. If the input equal or longer than word in dictionary check if all characters of dictionary word are present in input string. Few changes to `hasSameLetters` should be enough (also the name should be `containsSameLetters`.

Comment: For other problem, maybe just print the size of `words` wariable (instead of all words) and for others try using debugger.